# Cannot install WGET in Ubuntu 12.04.1 lts

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, wget

When installing wget through terminal it displays [image]

following error .I went through questions earlier asked on this topic and so I had added the results of echo $PATH and cat ~/.pam_environmententer image description here[image].Please help me to resolve this issue. Actually,I want to know what to do now as I am unable to understand what's going on.

Comment: Wget is already installed. And is not an error.

Comment: Can you tell me then how to run it.

Comment: By `wget` command.

Comment: in terminal it's showing"missing url"

Comment: So it works. You need to use some URL with wget.

Comment: @Pilot6 actually I don't know how to run it I just entered wget in terminal.Please let me know how to run it or use some URL .

Comment: What are you trying to do? Run `man wget` and read the manual how to use it.

Comment: wget is not a graphical program that pops up a box with an address bar like a browser. It's a *non-interactive* command line program, so you have to specify the url: wget http://www.someurl.com. :)

Comment: @Pilot6:  Could you please convert  the upvoted comment to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby I converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` is already installed.

`wget` is a command-line tool. You have to run it with an URL.

To get detailed instruction how to use `wget` you can run

```
man wget
```

**Example:**

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb
```

Comment: Perfect!  **;-)**